# Hide one element when I click on another one

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click the first link it sets `#foto` height to `200px`. If I click second link, it sets `#foto1` height to `200px`.

What I want is when clicking on 2nd link to set `#foto` height to `0px` and vice versa. Any help?

```js
function ver(fotox, texto1) {
  var x = document.getElementById(fotox);
  x.style.height = '200px';
  x.innerHTML = texto1;
}
```

```css
.link {
  padding: 10px
}

#foto,
#foto1 {
  background-color: orange;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link" onClick="ver('foto','hola')">1</a>
<div id="foto"> parte 1</div>
<a href="#" class="link" onClick="ver('foto1','chau')">3</a>
<div id="foto1"> Parte 2</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just add an height argument to your ver function?

Comment: toggle a class and keep it simple

Comment: @epascarello is right. See my answer for a snippet which does this in plain js. jQuery $.toggleClass() is a nice option too.

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set all the elements you want to toggle into a class. I've set them to linkDiv in my snippet below and toggle them accordingly. So if you're adding new elements whom you want to hide and show you can add them. Just add a class linkDiv to it.

```js
function ver(fotox,texto1) {
    var x = document.getElementById(fotox);
    if(x.style.height=="" || x.style.height=="0px")
    x.style.height= '200px';
    else 
    x.style.height='0px';
    x.innerHTML= texto1;
    var element=document.getElementsByClassName('linkDiv');
    for(var i=0; i<element.length;i++){
    if(element[i].getAttribute("id")!=fotox)
    {
    //console.log("compared "+element[i].getAttribute("id")+fotox);
    element[i].style.height= '0px';
    }
    }
    }
```

```css
.link {
        padding:10px

    }
    #foto, #foto1 {
        background-color:orange;
        margin-top: 20px;
        height: 0px;
        overflow:hidden
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link" onClick="ver('foto','hola')">1</a>
    <div id="foto" class="linkDiv"> parte 1</div>
    <a href="#" class="link" onClick="ver('foto1','chau')">3</a>
    <div id="foto1" class="linkDiv"> Parte 2</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! And how to close all on second click?

Comment: on second click of what? could you be more specific? Do you mean if you click any of the links for the second time all of the divs should close?

Comment: Great job. Now I'll try to analyze your script and figure out how does it work so I can learn from it. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Sure, Also in the above example you had two links. You could add as many as you want. Just remember to add the class linkDiv to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 4 arguments in your function in the following way:

```js
function ver(fotox1, fotox2, texto1, texto2) {
  var x = document.getElementById(fotox1);
  x.style.height = '200px';
  x.innerHTML = texto1;
  var y = document.getElementById(fotox2);
  y.style.height = '0px';
  y.innerHTML = texto2;
}
```

```css
.link {
  padding: 10px
}

#foto,
#foto1 {
  background-color: orange;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link" onClick="ver('foto','foto1','hola','')">1</a>
<div id="foto"> parte 1</div>
<a href="#" class="link" onClick="ver('foto1','foto', 'chau', '')">3</a>
<div id="foto1"> Parte 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a snippet. This code is concise and uses class-based styles instead of inline styles. Classes are the best practice.

```js
function ver(fotox, texto1) {
  var collection = document.getElementsByClassName("link")
  var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(collection, 0 );

  array.forEach(function(currentValue, index, array) {
    currentValue.className = 'link';
  });

  var x = document.getElementById(fotox);
  x.className = 'link active';
  x.innerHTML = texto1;
}
```

```css
#foto,
#foto1 {
  background-color: orange;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.link {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.link.active {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link" onClick="ver('foto','hola')">1</a>
<div id="foto"> parte 1</div>
<a href="#" class="link" onClick="ver('foto1','chau')">3</a>
<div id="foto1"> Parte 2</div>
```